# Tomcat jsp error "The type org.apache.axis2.AxisFault cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am using Tomcat 5.5 on Windows XP.

The tree is:

\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\Test
\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\Test\TestJsp.jsp
\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\Test\WEB-INF
\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\Test\WEB-INF\classes
\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\Test\WEB-INF\lib

I access the jsp via:

http://localhost:8090/Test/TestJsp.jsp

and get the error:

The type org.apache.axis2.AxisFault cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

This is contained inside axis2.jar and this jar is in the lib directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What version of axis2 are you running? Version 1.5 of Axis2 has org.apache.axis2.AxisFault in axis2-kernel-1.5.jar. Everything else looks correct (your directory structure, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you working with Eclipse, Take a look on the Target Runtime.

Go to the Web Services preference page and set the Axis2 Runtime location under Axis2 preferences.